# How to set active route link in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular5

I have the following link:

```
 <a routerLink="{{item._url}}" (click)="setActiveLink(i, item._url, menu)"
                [routerLinkActive]="['is-active']">Link</a>
```

How to extent `[routerLinkActive]` for custom URL to highlight link as active?

I can use `ngClass` but how to get url to compare with my url?

I did this:

```
<a [ngClass]="{'is-active': isUrl()}" routerLink="{{item._url}}" (click)="setActiveLink(i, item._url, menu)"
                [routerLinkActive]="['is-active']">{{item.title | translate}}</a>
```

And method is:

```
public isUrl(): boolean {
    const currentUrl = this.router.url;
    const arrUrl = ['replacements'];

    for (let i = 0; i < arrUrl.length; i++) {
      return currentUrl.indexOf(arrUrl[i]) > -1;
    }

    return false;
  }
```

It  highlights all links in menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `routerLinkActive="class-name"` and `routerLinkActiveOptions="{exact:true}"` for active route link?

> .html file

```
<nav>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="nav-content">
        <ul class="navbar-nav" id="nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="" routerLinkActive="class-name" routerLinkActiveOptions="{exact:true}">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/experience" routerLinkActive="class-name" routerLinkActiveOptions="{exact:true}">Experience</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/skills" routerLinkActive="class-name" routerLinkActiveOptions="{exact:true}">Skills</a>
          </li>
        <ul>
     <div>
<nav>
```

> css/.scss file

```
.class-name{
    color:red;
    ...
}
```

Comment: in case somebody comes looking for this: it works but I needed to use `[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }"`. notice the square brackets. otherwise, it always marks base path (e.g. *Home*) as active